# Async from Async.AwaitEvent and threading

Tags: multithreading, f#, async-await

This is a simplified version of a problem I deal with.
It has a threaded loop over which I have no control.
The time for me to process a message is more than the time for the loop to throw.

I can't rewrite anything in mytype beside the marked section in StartAsync.

Could you guide me to the instructions that could handle such conditions ?
For instance, is there a version of syncContext.Post with a queue ?
Any help appreciated

```
type mytype () = 
  let FinishedEvt    = new Event<_>()
  let FirstEvt       = new Event<_>()
  member x.First       = FirstEvt.Publish
  member x.Finished    = FinishedEvt.Publish

  member x.StartAsync() = 

     async {
     let syncContext =  match System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current with
                        | null -> new System.Threading.SynchronizationContext()
                        | other -> other 
     do! Async.SwitchToNewThread()
     //**the code that I can change is here**
     Thread.Sleep(100)
     syncContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback(fun _ -> FirstEvt.Trigger    ()), null)
     Thread.Sleep(200)
     syncContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback(fun _ -> FinishedEvt.Trigger ()), null)
     do! Async.SwitchToContext(syncContext) 
     ()
  }
     let hopingobject = mytype()
     let wf1 = lock readLock1 
                    (fun () -> 
                               async{ printfn "watching"
                                      do! Async.AwaitEvent hopingobject.First
                                      printfn "first event received"
                                      do! Async.AwaitEvent hopingobject.Finished
                                      printfn "I never get called"} )

     hopingobject.StartAsync() |> Async.Start
     wf1 |> Async.RunSynchronously
     printfn "the end"
     Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unclear what you're trying to do, and which parts are essential, but this bit

```
async{ printfn "watching" 
       do! Async.AwaitEvent hopingobject.First 
       printfn "first event received" 
       do! Async.AwaitEvent hopingobject.Finished 
       printfn "I never get called"}
```

looks wrong to me, since you don't start listening for Finished until after having processed First, at which point Finished may already have fired.  Perhaps you want something more like

```
async{ printfn "watching" 
       let! a = Async.AwaitEvent hopingobject.First |> Async.StartChild
       let! b = Async.AwaitEvent hopingobject.Finished |> Async.StartChild
       do! a
       printfn "first event received" 
       do! b
       printfn "hurray, I never called"}
```

(I am writing code in a browser, hope that is right.)  The idea is, start listening for both at the beginning, but then wait for First, and then wait for Finished.

Comment: indeed. I probably can deal with the problem that way. the combination of async continuations with the Async module's thread function are quite effing powerful.

Comment: with that construct I can do some heavy processing before do! b, and not miss the finished event, since its completion (aka the event firing) will be remembered in b.

Comment: actually, I had meanwhile realized that I would need to observe many chained events. I could have used AsyncObservable, but the number of chainching will be non deterministic. So I went for a mailboxprocessor with some multithread synchronization. I would not recommend it for a honeymoon.